How to fix C# code to send emails via SMTP server
I trying fix C# code to send email using SMTP server but I don't understand why I have a error like this Error, I asked chatgpt but I can't resolve and I also try to config sercure of gmail but not
there are code
try
{
    using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
    {
        mail.From = new MailAddress(fromEmail);
        mail.To.Add(toEmail);
        mail.Subject = subject;
        mail.Body = body;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = false; 

        using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)) // Thay đổi với SMTP server của bạn
        {
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromEmail, fromPassword);
            smtp.EnableSsl = true; // Bật SSL
            smtp.Send(mail);
        }
    }
}
catch (SmtpException ex) // Xử lý lỗi SMTP
{
    MessageBox.Show($"Lỗi gửi email: {ex.StatusCode} - {ex.Message}"); // Hiển thị thông báo lỗi
}
catch (Exception ex) // Xử lý các lỗi khác
{
    MessageBox.Show($"Lỗi: {ex.Message}"); // Hiển thị thông báo lỗi chung
}

I asked chatgpt but I can't resolve and I also try to config sercure of gmail but not

SmtpClient is outdated, see Remarks section in the documentation

https://stackoverflow.com/a/489594/17034

a.) use a different Smtp Client as already suggested b.) pure Credentials auth is on its way out. An App Password (not you standard account password) and opting for "less secure apps" might still work a few days but will be disallowed shortly also. You have to go for OAUTH2 See https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/imap-smtp?hl=en That is a auth method that SmtpClient does not support by the way.
